# Combinations or permutations ... or both?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have 6 values (A B C D E F)
how many unique combinations of 4 values are possible without repeating
(A A C D is wrong) and (A B C D is OK but A C B D is wrong)

Please list all combinations. THANKS!

I did:  $\dfrac{6!}{4!(6-4)!} = 15$??

How can I see a list of all combinations?

this is not what i wanted but is very funny:
http://youcanscience.com/science-fiction-friday-nine-billion-names-god-arthur-c-clarke/

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.  Remember that the combinations of four elements of a set are just the four-element subsets of $\{A, B, C, D, E, F\}$.  They are 
$$\{A, B, C, D\}, \{A, B, C, E\},  \{A, B, C, F\}, \{A, B, D, E\}, \{A, B, D, F\}, \{A, B, E, F\},  \{A, C, D, E\}, \{A, C, D, F\}, \{A, C, E, F\}, \{A, D, E, F\}, \{B, C, D, E\}, \{B, C, D, F\}, \{B, C, E, F\}, \{B, D, E, F\}, \{C, D, E, F\}$$
Had the question asked for the sequences of four elements that can be formed from the set $\{A, B, C, D, E, F\}$ without repetition, that would be a permutation problem since the order in which the elements are arranged would matter.  Notice that for each of the $\binom{6}{4}$ ways we could choose four elements of the set, we can arrange the chosen elements in $4!$ orders.  Hence, the number of such sequences is 
$$\binom{6}{4} \cdot 4!$$
Alternatively, we have six choices for the first position, five for the second position, four for the third position, and three for the fourth position, so there are 
$$6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$$
such sequences.  You should verify that 
$$\binom{6}{4} \cdot 4! = 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$$

Comment: thank you very much for editing and responding. Is there a way i can generate this list automatically? What if i have C(20,3), i don't want to do this by hand

Comment: I am afraid that I am not a programmer.  I just listed the sets alphabetically.  Perhaps GCab's method could be implemented by a program.  Another way might be to list all four-digit numbers using the digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ in numerical order, then equating each letter with its place in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create a list:First letter is A, B, or C.  Next letter is either B, C, or D, but later in list than first letter.  Similarly get third and fourth letters. Since you don't allow permutations, it will be complete.

For starter:
ABCD
ABCE
ABCF
ACDE
ACDF
ADEF

Answer (score 0):

Write down some rows each containing $A B,C,D,E,F$.
Then start and cancel $A,B$ in the first line, $A,C$ in the 2nd,  ..continuing with cancelling the $k$-th and $(k+j)$-th.  You get the list you want and a method to count the number of lines.

*Addendum*

Your problem goes  under the standard definition of
*"$m$-subsets from a $n$-set"*
and is equivalent to
*"strictly increasing words, of length $m$ from the alphabet $\{1, \cdots, n\}$"*.

As you could see the relevant number is given by ${n \choose m}$.

Concerning the generation of the list, any good CAS has a function to generate that.

However, without pretending to achieve maximal effectiveness, you can 
implement for instance the following recursion
We assume the letters to be replaced by natural numbers.

Denoting by $S(k,j)$ the subset of cardinality $k$ and last element $j$
$$
S(k,j)\quad \left| {\,1 \le k \le j \le n} \right. = \left\{ {x_{\,1} ,x_{\,2} , \cdots ,x_{\,k}  = j} \right\} \subset \left\{ {1,2, \cdots ,n} \right\}
$$
then you have the recurrence
$$
S(k + 1,j) = \bigcup\limits_{k \le l \le j - 1} {\left( {S(k,l) \cup \left\{ j \right\}} \right)} 
$$
so
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(1,j) = \left\{ j \right\}  \cr 
  & S(2,j) = \bigcup\limits_{2 \le l \le j - 1} {\left( {S(1,l) \cup \left\{ j \right\}} \right)}   \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \vdots  \cr} 
$$

Otherwise you can automatize the method I suggested above,
by creating the list of the items to cancel  with the loop

for $x[1]$ from 1 to n-m+1
$\;$ for $x[2]$ from $x[1]$ to $n-m+2$
$ \quad \quad  \vdots $
$\; \; \; $ for $x[m]$ from $x[m-1]$ to $n$
and then cancel these from the base set.

Comment: it works, thank you. I came to the same number 15, but again, how can i generate this list automatically for example C(20,3) will take a whole day using your method.